# How to convert this code from VB to Delphi

Tags: vb.net, delphi

```
Public Function GetChecksum(AsciText As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(AsciText)
        GetChecksum = GetChecksum Xor Asc(Mid$(AsciText, i, 1))
    Next i
End Function
```

I no have idea for "Mid$" on Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, that code is not VB.net, it is VB6 or VBA. Now, `Mid$` is the function for extracting sub strings. In Delphi it corresponds to `Copy`. However, since you are only extracting a single character, you should use the `[]` indexing operator instead. Overall the function would look something like this.

```
function GetChecksum(const Input: AnsiString): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(Input) do 
    Result := Result xor ord(Input[i]);
end;
```

I believe that in the original VB6 code `Integer` is a 16 bit value. In Delphi `Integer` is a 32 bit value. I don't think that this matters since only the low 8 bits are used. You might change the return type of the Delphi code to the 8 bit unsigned `Byte` type though.

Note also that you have to be content with the fact that you code relies on the text being encoded with some 8 bit encoding. What are you going to do if you want to use Unicode text?

Comment: Delphi also has `LeftStr()`, `MidStr()`, and `RightStr()` functions, which are similar to VB's `Left()`, `Mid()` and `Right()` functions.

Answer (score -2):

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Try
        Dim wc As New Net.WebClient
        wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
        Dim wb As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim sr As String = wb.DownloadString("")
        Dim regex As New Regex("")
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = regex.Matches(sr)
        For Each element As Match In matches
            ListBox1.Items.Add(element.Value)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I have no idea what are you trying to achieve here